# How to set Image position relative to another Image on Android

Tags: android, image

I try to explain my problem. I have two ImageViews. 
One of them is the background image and large as well.

This background image has also a zoom function. The other Image is a small image with size of 36x36.

The small image can be moved around the screen:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    //Definition MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK: Bit mask of the parts of the action code that are the action itself.
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
    }
    viewGroup.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

If i zoom in the background image, the small image doesn't zoom. It's position is absolute to the screen and not to the Image.

How can i make the small Image to be relative to the large Image?

I hope it's clear what my Problem is.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/skizze"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/feuerloescher"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:src="@drawable/feuerloescher"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your XML layout?

Comment: Observer background image zoom, get coefficient of zoom, and use this coefficient to change size of small image. I don't know another ways

Comment: added the xml layout

Answer (score 0):

try with `android:layout_below="@id/skizze"`

Try as following xml code

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/skizze"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/feuerloescher"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:src="@drawable/feuerloescher"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/skizze" />
```

Comment: The second ImageView has still the absolute position on screen. :/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post however just in case it helps I just had this same issue and was able to resolve it as follows.

```
android:layout_alignTop="@id/app_bg_fill"
```

"alignTop" seemed to be the key line. Full code follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg_fill"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_bg_fill"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:src="@drawable/guide_item_2f"
    android:background="@drawable/view_frame_style" />
     

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="12sp"
    android:text="SomeText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/app_bg_fill" 
    android:textColor="#000000" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```